# How do I select a particular column in a HTML table with no ID?

Tags: php, foreach, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using SimpleHTMLDOM and I have two tables with identical columns and I need to extract the column titles?

[image: Sample Picture]

Below is what I am using to get all the data but now I need to only select the Month and corresponding column titles (jan, feb, etc)

```
 $r_tables = $dom->find('table');

foreach($r_tables as $table) {
    $r_cells = $table->find('td');

    foreach($r_cells as $cell) {
        echo $cell->plaintext.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is ...

```
$tables = $dom->find('table');

foreach($tables as $table) {
    $r_cells = $table->find('tr');
    $i = 0;
    foreach($r_cells as $row) {
        $cell = $row->find('td');
        if ($i == 0) {
            foreach($cell as $td) { 
                echo $td.'<br />';
            }
        }  
    $i++;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankss again @herb.  This worked but it repeats the results twice... Could it be because I have 2 tables with identical column names?

Comment: ALso, if I wanted to organize all this in an html table, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I am sort of new to this but can you clarify how you were able to do this? It would help me figure out the rest.

Comment: @KPO - yes the line foreach($tables as $table) loops through every table on the page

Answer (score 0):

a crude way would be

```
$i = 0;
foreach($r_tables as $table) {
$r_cells = $table->find('td');

foreach($r_cells as $cell) {
  if($i == 0) {    
    echo $cell->plaintext.'<br />';
  }    
}
$i++;
```

}

Comment: Couldn't you just do `echo $r_cells[0]->plaintext;`? (never used SimpleHTMLDom)

Comment: Thanks @herb.  This works but it also shows the second row, which i don't want.   How should I remove that and only have month row?

Comment: I would need to see your code behind $table->find('td') but i presumed $r_cells was a table row

Comment: @herb Can you please clarify what exactly you need to see?

Comment: I would need to see what was behind the $table->find('td') object method. Does it return a row at a time. I am thinking because you got back everything that you might be trying to execute something along the lines of $table->find('tr') before you divide it up into individual cells

Comment: @herb I don't have anything else.  All the object method code is in the question.  I am not sure what else to add there..

Comment: @supericy I used your suggestion and it seems to do the trick but it returns the results 5 times.  Why is it doing that?

Comment: @KPO Remove the second for loop (ie `foreach ($r_cells as cell)`). And just have the 1 call. I added my own answer to your question as well, you can take a look there for the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Find the td's from the first tr of the first table:

```
$tds = $dom->find('table', 0)->find('tr', 0)->find('td');
```

Map the text of each td into an array:

```
$headers = array_map(function($td){return $td->text();}, $tds);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want (If I understand correctly):

```
foreach($r_tables as $table) {
    $r_cells = $table->find('td');

    echo $r_cells[0]->plaintext . '<br />';;
}
```